# How to customize my own 0x exchange

Tags: 0x

I would like to know how my custom ERC721 0x marketplace can be customized.
I know the FAQ has a walkthrough and I already found out how to inject my custom ERC20 token address, symbols etc. but I still have a problem replacing the logo for my exchange or marketplace.
I wonder if a documentation also exists regarding that topic? (I was able to replace to logo, but I can't get rid off the applied css filter that makes the svg paths green / grey depending on the theme applied).
I would also be curious how the collectibles card can be changed?